# Flex Text html format conversion to HTML

Tags: html, apache-flex, flex4.6, data-conversion, richeditabletext

I have an application where you can configure some pages using the `RichTextEditor` and storing the resulting HTML Text Flow to database to use later...

If I import the saved datas to Flex using a `RichEditableText` there is no problem at all and I see the expected result (visually and graphically)...

To convert the stored HTML String into a TextFlow I use:

`header.textFlow = TextConverter.importToFlow(p.FIELD, 
                                           TextConverter.TEXT_FIELD_HTML_FORMAT);`

I would like to use the stored HTML String in a single HTML web page and not in a flash environment... 
Can I do this using some native classes/functions that convert the adobe HTML format to a standard HTML?

this is an example of the stored HTML String:

```
<TEXTFORMAT LEADING="2"><P ALIGN="LEFT"><FONT FACE="Arial" SIZE="12" COLOR="#000000"
     LETTERSPACING="0" KERNING="0">This is an example.</FONT></P></TEXTFORMAT>
```

If I copy&paste the above code in a html page the final result it's similar to the one I get in Flash/Flex but the font/s are much bigger, and some tags are not html tags...

Answer (score 0):

How do you export HTML for database? Try using:

```
var htmlStringForDB:String = TextConverter.export(
          customEditor.editor.textFlow,
          TextConverter.TEXT_FIELD_HTML_FORMAT,
          ConversionType.STRING_TYPE).toString();
```

like in this [example](http://blog.flexexamples.com/2009/07/25/exporting-a-textflow-object-in-flex-4/).